# Configuring V8 for building with /MD with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, v8, gyp

Does anyone know if its possible to configure V8 to be built this way with VS2010? I am trying to embed V8 in a project that already uses a few libraries configured for the multi-threaded DLL(/MD) runtime library on Windows and V8 is by default configured for /MT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingWithGYP

I found the answer under the XCode section, you need to use the command...

```
python build/gyp_v8 -Dcomponent=shared_library
```

to generate your project files, apparently it also works for VS